# getting the image width from the href tag instead from img tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, width

i am working on a project in which i require the width of a image from href when i click on the specific image the width if the image displays in a alert .

the following is the href and image code i am using

```
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $pic;?>?id=<?php echo $id;?>&pic=<?php echo $picID;?>" data-title="" data-desc=" " data-rel="group2" data-bw="<?php echo $pic;?>"  class="lightbox" id="plzx" >
      <img src="<?php echo $pic;?>"  width="160" height="160" title="Click To View"/></a>                       
    </li>
```

whenever i try to get the width of the image it takes the image width from the img tag not from the href . as the img tag width is already defined "160" . is there a way possible for getting the width of the image from the `<a href`

i am using the following code which is nit working

```
   $('a').click(function() {
       var image = $("<img />").attr("src", $(".lightbox").attr("href"));
       $(document).append(image);
       alert(image.height());
       alert(image.width());
       image.remove();
    });
```

**the html code**

```
       <li>
                    <a href="uploads/kareena-kapoor-144a_$1$Ni5.St4.$kPORmHFjcfGBJjn2KHSis0.jpg?id=3&pic=101" data-title="" data-desc=" " data-rel="group2" data-bw="uploads/kareena-kapoor-144a_$1$Ni5.St4.$kPORmHFjcfGBJjn2KHSis0.jpg"  class="lightbox" id="plzx" >

                    <img src="uploads/kareena-kapoor-144a_$1$Ni5.St4.$kPORmHFjcfGBJjn2KHSis0.jpg"  width="160" height="160" title="Click To View"/></a>

    </li>
```

Comment: where u have set width and height in `href`??

Comment: when you say the width from the href? Do you mean the <a> tag, or does the href attribute of the <a> tag contain the width as part of the href/filename? e.g href="image120_140.jpg" and it needs to be extracted? what happens if you do alert($(this).width());

Comment: When you say "get the width from the href" what do you mean? Do you mean the href of the image contains the width that the image is served at? Like for example `<a href='script.php?img=image.jpg&width=200&height=300'>` and you want to get `200` from the string, or you want to load the image and determine the width of the image that was served dynamically?

Comment: As you can see from the previous comments, please show us the "final" HTML browser code instead of PHP

Comment: whiwh `Lightbox` plugin you are using??

Comment: yes i want the width from the href tag image which is comming dynamically and i havnet set any height or width of that dynamic image

Comment: see the view source of page and tell us how exactly it forming the `href`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on something like:

```
<a href="/path/to/big.jpg"><img src="/path/to/small.jpg"></a>
```

This should do it:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(new Image()).load(function() {
        alert(this.width); // image width
        alert(this.height); // image height
    }).attr('src', this.href);
});
```

**Update**: If you need to continue your program using the width/height, try:

```
var width,height;
$('a').click(function() {
    $(new Image()).load(function() {
        width = this.width;
        height = this.height,
        onLoaded();
    }).attr('src', this.href);
});
function onLoaded() {
    alert(width);
    alert(height);
    // continue...
}
```

You don’t need to append the temporary image to the document, but you do need to add a load listener before you extract width/height.

Remember that the AdBlock extension can affect the outcome of the extraction in webkit, so please turn it off when debugging.

Comment: it should be `.attr('src', this.href);` I guess

Comment: thanks a lot @David and devnull69 its working . can u please tell me how to store the width in a var

Comment: @SakshiSharma You can’t "store" it, since it is only available inside the load handler. If you need to continue your program, use the handler as a starting point (see my edit)

Comment: You can do this with `myvar = this.width;` inside the .load()

Comment: emmm. is this possible to hold the value till i am in that page , i have to use that value of image to give width to a lightbox .

Comment: @SakshiSharma You can trigger the lightbox inside the ´onLoaded´ function. But I feel like we are moving out of topic here, please post a new question if you want to ask something else.

Comment: @David i almost near to make what i wanted my mistake is there a way i can get the width without using click event ?

Comment: @SakshiSharma replace 'click' with 'each'

Comment: by using each . i am getting width of all the images in the gallery at the same time . for eg - there are 7 images all 7 images width are alerted even before the page loads up . i want the width of the image which i am currently viewing